# cant align in the middle of the page a button in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't align this button in the middle of the page it doesn't work.

[image: my css for the button]

Comment: Images of code are not allowed. Copy and paste the code into the question instead.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: if you want to algin anything in the center always give `display: block` to your element and `margin: auto` and width as much you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Questions of such poor quality should not be answered. For one thing, you have no layout context. Your solution is a generic wild guess. For another, it's almost certainly a duplicate many times over.